# Factoring big numbers into primes

Tags: factoring

I can't find a good tutorial anywhere on how to factor big numbers into primes, so I was wondering if someone could explain the process. I need to do this for my cryptology class.

Comment: There is a huge literature, e.g., see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_factorization). It lists several algorithms to factor an integer.

Comment: @DietrichBurde thanks! I just wasn't sure if I can trust wikipedia, but I'll check it out!

Comment: If you are interested, see also [here](http://homepage.univie.ac.at/Dietrich.Burde/papers/burde_30_crypto_course.pdf).

Comment: See [The Joy of Factoring](http://www.ams.org/bookstore-getitem?item=STML-68).